# Hover effect in CSS stops working on certain elements once I change theme of the page, including the element, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-animations

I'm working on a portfolio website and I have a menu bar at the top with 3 buttons.
My issue is that, when I change the theme of the page from dark to light with a toggle, effects on hover for some elements such as buttons stops working.

HTML

```
<div class="container-menu">
    <button class="menu-button" id="home">Home</button>
    <button class="menu-button" id="project">Projects</button>
    <button class="menu-button" id="about">About Me</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-menu{
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 20em;
}
.menu-button{
    font-size: 20;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 2em;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border: 0;  
    background-color: rgb(10, 0, 10);
    color: #f0f0f0;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

I have a toggle switch that changes the page from light mode to dark mode with the help of javascript.

js

```
const checkbox=document.querySelector(".theme-checkbox");
const containertop=document.querySelector(".container-top");
const menubuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-button");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if(checkbox.checked){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="#f0f0f0";
        document.body.style.color="#0a000a";
        containertop.style.backgroundColor="#f0f0f0";
        menubuttons.forEach((button) => {
            button.style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";
            button.style.color = "#0a000a";
        });
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="#0a000a";
        document.body.style.color="#f0f0f0";
        containertop.style.backgroundColor="#0a000a";
        menubuttons.forEach((button) => {
            button.style.backgroundColor = "#0a000a";
            button.style.color = "#f0f0f0";
        });
    }
});
```

Just giving

```
.menu-button:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 105, 105);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

Makes the color of the button change when I hover but once I toggle to light mode or even toggle back to dark mode, the hover effect does not work. This seems to be some issue with the fact that I am changing the color of the text on hover as well as during theme change. Is there any way to get around this?

Doing the following works but it is unstable. When i switch to light mode, the text color changes to the hover color and when I hover over the button, it changes back to black and then the hover function works. Is there any alternative to this?

```
.menu-button:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 105, 105) !important;
    transition-duration: 0.3s !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the styles directly on your Javascript, change to a toggle to add a property definid on your CSS code (`Dark mode` and `Light Mode`), and then you can definy the styles for your button for both modes.

CSS:

```
.dark-mode {
    background-color: rgb(10, 0, 10);
    color: #f0f0f0;
}

.light-mode {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #0a000a;
}
.menu-button:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 105, 105);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const checkbox=document.querySelector(".theme-checkbox");
const containertop=document.querySelector(".container-top");
const menubuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-button");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if(checkbox.checked){
        document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
        document.body.classList.add("light-mode");
        containerTop.classList.remove("dark-mode");
        containerTop.classList.add("light-mode");
        });
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("light-mode");
        document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
        containerTop.classList.remove("light-mode");
        containerTop.classList.add("dark-mode");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this as a reference to fix the code as follows
`menubuttons.forEach((button) => {
            button.classList.remove("light-mode");
            button.classList.add("dark-mode");
        });`
And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute is more important than class.

You can change this behavior by adding a custom class name instead of a "style" attribute"

```
 document.body.classList.add("dark");
```

and create a css class for that:

```
.dark {
  background-color: #0a000a;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think both Alex and Dansky answers are good answers.

You are basically adding a style attribute into the button tag with javascript,
So the result of that script, is that after the button is clicked you will have an inline style for that button, something like this:

```
<button class="menu-button" id="about" style="background-color:#0a000a;color:#f0f0f0;">
```

and something you want to avoid,
as the inline style attribute is stronger than any other css class instruction you can assign after, and will win over any other instruction.
I added an example of inline style in one button just to show the effect of it.

To add "dark-mode" class to the body with javascript, using
`classlist.add("dark-mode")`
or, as I suggest here,
`classList.toggle("dark-mode")`
will require less javascript code,
and you can then style all the elements in the css part, using '.dark-mode .your_element_class' or '.dark-mode #your_element_id'

See an example with the css, js and html in one page,

then if you have the same background in the menu container, in the body and for the buttons, I would think that the buttons are like transparent buttons, and I would remove the button's background color from the css, but that really depends on your project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    
    <style>
    body{
        /* added style for the page, for demo purpose.
        base font size is declared here 1em = 16px in many modern browsers  */
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 1em auto;
        padding: 0;
        /* default mode style of body  */
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        color: #0a000a;
    }
    /* body + dark mode - dark mode style of body  */
    .dark-mode {
        background-color: #0a000a;
        color: #f0f0f0;
    }

     .container-menu{
        padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        /* width removed temporarily, as button resulted cut
        width: 20em; 
        */
    }
    .menu-button{
        /* font size were declared as '20' without units, changed to 1.2 (19 px circa)  */
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        /* width/height removed temporarily, as menu items were not spaced around with this
        width: fit-content;
        height: 2em;
        */
        padding: 0 auto;
        border: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* default mode style of menu buttons  */
        background: #f0f0f0;
        color: #0a000a;
    }
    /* menu-button + dark mode - dark mode style of menu buttons  */
    .dark-mode .menu-button{
      background: #0a000a;
      color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    .menu-button:hover{
        color: rgb(255, 105, 105);
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-menu">
    <button class="menu-button" id="home">Home</button>
    <button class="menu-button" id="project">Projects</button>
    <button class="menu-button" id="about">About Me</button>
    <!-- added a button to show what happens with inline style -->
    <button class="menu-button" id="override" style="background-color:#0a000a;color:#f0f0f0;">Try to hover</button>
    <!-- added a button to toggle the dark mode -->
    <button class="menu-button" id="darkMode" onclick="toggleMode()"> Toggle Mode</button>
</div>


<script>
    //function triggered by button darkMode
    function toggleMode() {
      var el = document.body;
      //each time the function is triggered, it adds or removes the class
      el.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I also found that the font size you declared fo the buttons was "20" without the unit (px, em, % etc) but that was not causing issues with the rest of the css instructions.